# Clear input data after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to clear my input field after button click. I have tried several ways but it doesn't clear the input field. It shows the previous value every time.

```js
function addTodo() {
  var todoItem = document.getElementById("todo-item").value;
  if (todoItem === "") {
    alert("Please enter task");
  } else {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var liText = document.createTextNode(todoItem);
    li.appendChild(liText);
    list.appendChild(li);

    var editBtn = document.createElement("i");
    editBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "editTodo(this)");
    editBtn.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-pencil-square-o");
    li.appendChild(editBtn);

    var deleteBtn = document.createElement("i");
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-remove")
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteTodo(this)");
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    todoItem.value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.value` from `var todoItem = ...` and place it `if (todoItem.here === "") ...` and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addTodo() {
    var todoItem = document.getElementById("todo-item").value;
    if (todoItem === "") {
        alert("Please enter task");
    } else {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var liText = document.createTextNode(todoItem);
        li.appendChild(liText);
        list.appendChild(li);
    
        var editBtn = document.createElement("i");
        editBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "editTodo(this)");
        editBtn.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-pencil-square-o");
        li.appendChild(editBtn);
    
        var deleteBtn = document.createElement("i");
        deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-remove")
        deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteTodo(this)");
        li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        document.getElementById("todo-item").value = "";
    }

}
```

`todoItem` was not the input element it was rather holding it's value

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should cache the element and then use it or mutate its data, please pay attention to the below:

```js
function addTodo() {
  var todoItem = document.getElementById("todo-item");
  var todoItemValue = todoItem.value;

  if (todoItemValue === "") {
    alert("Please enter task");
  } else {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var liText = document.createTextNode(todoItemValue);
    li.appendChild(liText);
    list.appendChild(li);

    var editBtn = document.createElement("i");
    editBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "editTodo(this)");
    editBtn.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-pencil-square-o");
    li.appendChild(editBtn);

    var deleteBtn = document.createElement("i");
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-remove")
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteTodo(this)");
    li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    todoItem.value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it does not clear input field.

Comment: it's not my code. it is your code @WaqasUmer, I just fix it.

Comment: yes I mean the code you fixed didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @WaqasUmer, I send a new edit, try this